# Vertical-align a variable-size image in a div?

Tags: css, image, html, vertical-alignment

**Edit: A note to anyone reading this, the whole reason it didn't work for me is because I was using DOCTYPE TRANSITIONAL. Which no change in HTML or CSS whatsoever, switching to DOCTYPE STRICT made it work. This is true for at least Chrome, FF, and IE8.**

I have tried many many solutions offered online and none of them seem to work for me. I am trying to vertical-align an image inside a div (the image is already horizontal-aligned).

The image can be any width and any height (up to 70px) so I can't use a fixed margin or anything like that.

Here is my HTML+CSS:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    #list ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #list li {
        border: 2px solid #DDD;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        height: 110px;
    }
    #image {
        width: 75px;
        height: 110px;
        line-height: 110px;
        float: left;
    }
    #image img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #event {
        margin-left: 75px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div id="list">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div id='image'>
                    <img src='http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico'/>
                </div>
                <div id='event'>
                    <h1>Text</h1>
                    <h2>More Text</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id='image'>
                    <img src='http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico'/>
                </div>
                <div id='event'>
                    <h1>Text</h1>
                    <h2>More Text</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `vertical-align` on a block element.  An image is usually an inline element, but you have yours explicitly set to `display: block`.  Remove that, and set the `line-height` of the parent div to the div's height.

Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/YnzR9/1/

```
#image {
    width: 75px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
}
#image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Now the image **doesn't** center horizontally, still doesn't center vertically, and my lines of text are huge (due to each of them having a 110px line-height). Maybe I'm understanding wrong?

Comment: You were centering it using `margin: auto`, which doesn't work on inline elements.  Instead, use `text-align: center` on the parent element.  Fixed here:  http://jsfiddle.net/YnzR9/1/

Comment: A note to anyone reading this, the whole reason it didn't work for me is because I was using DOCTYPE TRANSITIONAL. Which no change in HTML or CSS whatsoever, switching to DOCTYPE STRICT made it work. This is true for at least Chrome, FF, and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "line-height" of the div to the same value as the height of the div.

Update: Assuming you want the image vertically aligned and centered, use the following.

```
#image {
    width: 75px;
    height: 110px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 110px;
    text-align:center;
}
#image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix anything:
    #image {
        width: 75px;
        height: 110px;
 line-height: 110px;
        float: left;
    }

Comment: You didn't say which div to put the line-height in, I think I tried them all and nothing worked.

Comment: gilly3 mentions that the `display:block` negates the line height. Assuming you want the image vertically aligned and centered, see updated post.